# Is there a way to compute the determinant of such a matrix without having to resort Ruffini

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus

$$
\begin{pmatrix} 
k & -15 & k \\
-\dfrac53 & k & -\dfrac53\\
-5 & -15 & k\\ 
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Is there a way to compute the determinant of such a matrix without having to resort Ruffini, in order to obtain the related decomposed polynomial? using ruffini I get that det can be written as $(k + 5)^2(k − 5)$, but it is too time consuming.

Comment: Yes, there is the [Rule of Sarrus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_Sarrus). It is not "time consuming".

Comment: Consider this determinant as a function $f(k)$ and "notice" that $f(5) = f(-5)=0$.

Comment: Using sarrus we get $k^3+5k^2-25k+125$ to be decomposed via Ruffini. Don't we?

Comment: Subtract 3rd row from 1st row, the new 1st row has only one non-zero entry,  the determinant essentially become a $2\times 2$ one....

Comment: No, you don't need Ruffini for "factoring". See [Integer polynomial factorising](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization_of_polynomials#Factoring_univariate_polynomials_over_the_integers). It is rather trivial in this case, since you have the root $5$ by the rational root theorem.

Comment: @achillehui this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this determinant as a function $f(k)$. It's easy to notice that
$$
f(5) = f(-5) = 0.
$$
Indeed, corresponding rows would be proportional.

It means that
$$
f(k) = (k-5)(k+5)(k+a)
$$
for some $a$. Now we need to find $a$. It's easy to see that $a = 5$, since there is only one permutation which does not contatin $k$ and
$$
-5\cdot 5 \cdot a = (-15)\cdot \frac{-5}{3} \cdot (-5)
$$
so $a = 5$.